# Django Nested Serializer Issue: Field name is not valid for model

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to setup the following output:

```
{
    season: 1,
    player_profile: {
        name: John Doe,
    }
}
```

The models are setup as such:

```
class PlayerProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)

class TeamAffinityReward(models.Model):
    player_profile = models.OneToOneField(
        PlayerProfile,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        #db_constraint=False
        null=True)
    season = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

The serializers are setup like this:

```
class PlayerProfileForNestingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PlayerProfile
        fields = (
            'name',
        )


class TeamAffinityRewardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TeamAffinityReward
        playerprofile = PlayerProfileForNestingSerializer()
        fields = (
            'playerprofile',
            'season',
        )
```

However, I get the following error: `` Field name `playerprofile` is not valid for model `TeamAffinityReward`. ``

If I change `playerprofile` to `player_profile`, the error goes away but it displays the player_profile_ID instead of the PlayerProfileForNestingSerializer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining the `player_profile` field in `Meta`, you should declare it as a class variable:

```py
class TeamAffinityRewardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    player_profile = PlayerProfileForNestingSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = TeamAffinityReward
        fields = (
            'player_profile',
            'season',
        )
```